# AirDrop Photo Wrong

Tags: macos, ios, airdrop

When I open AirDrop on my Mac (10.12.2), my iPhone (10.2) shows up but the picture is wrong.  I'm not even sure who it is or where it comes from.
[image: AirDrop]

My wife's picture is correct though.  I've checked my Contact Card on both my Mac and my iPhone and they both have the correct photo of me.

Answer (score 1):

Airdrop appears to use the picture stored in iCloud.  To change it

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open the iCloud preference pane
3. Click the picture to change it.